# Can a car seat be swapped for a more comfortable one

Tags: car, seat

If I have a car that has a poor quality car seat can it be changed to one with better back support or does it need to be a seat from the same manufacturer?

Although it's possible to buy attachment for car seats I'd suspect a better quality car seat is preferable to a cover.

Comment: You can get a car seat *cover* that provides lumbar support.

Comment: Re the question edit: perhaps there is a higher spec version of the same car with a better seat, to be found in a vehicle breaker's yard.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sadly not, the higher end version is just leather instead of cloth. So essentially lipstick on a 

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get any aftermarket supports etc to help with your seating position. The only other option is welding in a new set of rails for a different seat.
If you have a welder of know someone who can properly weld. You can then fit any necessary adjustment/riser blocks to the vehicles floor. Then mark up the new seats runner holes, and tap some new threads into the new blocks you fitted. Then you can fit any seat you prefer.

I'm making it sound easy here but with the right equipment its definitely possible.